# Django celery beat task not working

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

**celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'TwitterApiProxy.settings')

app = Celery('TwitterApiProxy')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    # Calls test('hello') every 10 seconds.
    sender.add_periodic_task(10.0, hello_test.s('hello'), name='add every 10')


@app.task
def hello_test(arg):
    print(arg)
```

**settings.py**

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'
```

I want to print "hello" every 10 seconds. So on running `celery -A TwitterApiProxy beat` in my terminal, I see as below:

```
LocalTime -> 2018-04-06 23:27:09
Configuration ->
    . broker -> redis://localhost:6379//
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%WARNING
    . maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s)
```

it did not print anything related to the task that I scheduled. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I do my configuration a little different, but before I answer, I am curious about 2 things. 1: Your function "setup_periodic_tasks", can you put a print statement to see if it is actually being called? 2: There is an assumption that you are running a celery worker for the app. Is that assumption correct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your set up.

Start your worker and celery beat in two separate cmd windows

```
celery -A TwitterApiProxy worker -l info
celery -A TwitterApiProxy beat -l info
```

If you are using Celery 4.0+, you have to install [eventlet](http://eventlet.net/) first, then start your worker like this:

```
celery -A TwitterApiProxy worker -l info -P eventlet
```

**Task Admin Backend**

If you want a task admin backend, you can install and use [django-celery](https://github.com/celery/django-celery)

Comment: starting celery 3.1, it supports Django directly. so no need to add additional library like django-celery

Comment: @LokeshCherukuri I run your code in my app. Worked fine for me. See my edited answer. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: You saved my day, thanks!!! I tried all day long with `beat` but without `worker` in a separate window (facepalm)

Comment: Why is eventlet required with celery 4.0+ ?